# Как сделать автоматический переключатель субтитров игре Life is Strange?

Tags: разработка-игр

Я хочу забиндить кнопку, чтобы переключать субтитры во время игры. Как это сделать?

Comment: Life is Strange не является открытой игрой, и нет официального API для переключения субтитров во время игры.

Comment: Один способ - это использовать утилиту для управления игрой, такую как AutoHotkey, которая позволяет задать комбинацию клавиш для переключения субтитров. Но это может повлиять на стабильность игры

Comment: Как вариант - написать разработчикам, попросить добавить такую фичу.

Comment: Т.е нужно забиндить esc+стрелка вниз+enter+стрелка вниз+стрелка влево?